# Scala error in the logs after deploying the project on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

[image]

I don't use Scala anywhere in my project still getting this error. Cannot find the root cause here.

Comment: Please don't upload images of stacktraces. Copy the text

Comment: you're using the horrible old scala consumer for kafka. please dont :-)

Answer (score 1):

Kafka uses Scala internally, however Zookeeper isn't used for Consumers any longer, so I suggest you try using a newer version of spring-kafka